# Disable form element when checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In my rails application I have this two field in my form and I tried to disable the end_date field when the check box is checked so for this I have the jQuery code below

```
<div class="form-profile end-date">
  <%= f.label :experience_end, class: "profile_label" %><br/>
  <%= f.date_select :experience_end, {start_year: 1945, discard_day: true, order: [ :day, :month, :year ]}, :html=> {class: 'date-select'} %>
</div>

<div class="form-checkbox">
  <%= f.check_box :experience_current,class: 'is_current', id: "checkbox_id" %>
  I currently work here
</div>
```

The jQuery code

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("input[class='is_current']").click(function() {
          if($('#checkbox_id').prop("checked")) {
            $('.end-date select').prop(
                'disabled', true
            );
            $('.end-date select').css(
                "background-color", "#D9D8DD"
          );

          } else {
                $('.end-date select').prop(
                    'disabled', false
                );
                $('.end-date select').css(
                    "background-color", "white"
                );
          }
        });
    });
```

This work just fine except when I'm submitting the form and try to access it again to edit it, in this case I found that the checkbox is checked but the form is not disabled, So I'm wondering on How can I resolve this isuue

Comment: Try to add `.click()` at the end. it will execute your click handler on init.

Comment: where exactly to add the click()

Comment: `$("input[class='is_current']").click(function() { .... }).click();`

Comment: This solution just uncheck the checkbox everytime i reload the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only disabling the form field on `click` of the checkbox. So when the page (re)loads, no click event has been triggered, so no logic is performed. One possible way around this is to abstract the logic in to a function, which is called both on page load and on `click` of the checkbox.

```
function disableStuff() {
  // Perform disable logic
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  disableStuff();    
  $('.selector').click(function() {
    disableStuff();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for disabling the element on document ready.

Try this:

```
 function disableEndDate() {
   if($('#checkbox_id').prop("checked")) {
     $('.end-date select').prop(
         'disabled', true
     );
     $('.end-date select').css(
         "background-color", "#D9D8DD"
   );
 }

function enableEndDate() {
  $('.end-date select').prop(
            'disabled', false
   );
   $('.end-date select').css(
     "background-color", "white"
   );
 }

 $(document).ready(function() {
    disableEndDate();

    $("input[class='is_current']").click(function() {
        disableEndDate();
      } else {
        enableEndDate();
      }
    });
});
```

**You should improve it much more by aggregating logic into functions.**

Answer (score 0):

If your page reloaded, this might work:

```
if ($('input.is_curent').prop('checked')) {
    $('.end-date select').prop(
        'disabled', false
    );
    $('.end-date select').css(
        "background-color", "white"
    ); 
}
```

The code above simply checks if the checkbox is checked and disables the form element depending on the state of the checkbox.